# Android checkbox how to remove left padding

Tags: android, checkbox, layout, padding, margin

[image]

How can I modify the red line space (Set it to 0)? I would like my box just in my vertical guideline.

android:layout_marginLeft is doing nothing.

android:paddingLeft is modifying the space between the box and the text.

minSdkVersion is 16

Comment: I don't think you can remove it directly, it's part of the drawable. Otherwise try `android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to try

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Works for me and important to note that you must use MaterialCheckBox from com.google.android.material